# Micronaut test fileupload

Tags: java, mocking, micronaut

I want to test a method, which receives a CompletedFileUpload.

```
public void uploadZip(String orderId, CompletedFileUpload fileUpload) throws IOException {

    Path path = Files.createTempFile("file-", "-temp");
    File tempFile = path.toFile();
    try (FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(tempFile)) {
        outputStream.write(fileUpload.getBytes());
        someMethod(orderId, tempFile);
    }
}
```

The CompletedFileUpload is an interface:

```
package io.micronaut.http.multipart;

public interface CompletedFileUpload extends FileUpload, CompletedPart {
}
```

I want to find a way to Mock the File upload, for spring boot i found :

```
MockMultipartFile multipartFile =
                new MockMultipartFile("springboot.png", "springboot.png", "image/png", "".getBytes());
```

Is there something similar that I can use in Micronaut?

Answer (score 1):

You can build your own MockFileUpload test class the way Spring does:

```
public class MockFileUpload implements CompletedFileUpload {

    private final String filename;

    private final MediaType mediaType;

    private final byte[] content;

    public MockFileUpload(String filename, MediaType mediaType) {
        this(filename, mediaType, null);
    }

    public MockFileUpload(String filename, MediaType mediaType, @Nullable byte[] content) {
        this.filename = filename;
        this.mediaType = mediaType;
        this.content = (content != null ? content : new byte[0]);
    }

    @Override
    public InputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {
        return new ByteArrayInputStream(content);
    }

    @Override
    public byte[] getBytes() throws IOException {
        return content;
    }

    @Override
    public ByteBuffer getByteBuffer() throws IOException {
        return ByteBuffer.wrap(content);
    }

    @Override
    public Optional<MediaType> getContentType() {
        return Optional.of(mediaType);
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return filename;
    }

    @Override
    public String getFilename() {
        return filename;
    }

    @Override
    public long getSize() {
        return content.length;
    }

    @Override
    public long getDefinedSize() {
        return content.length;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isComplete() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

and then in your tests you can use the class this way:

`CompletedFileUpload file = new MockFileUpload("invoice.pdf", MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF_TYPE);`